# Odoo Many2many field only get single record with loop also

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

I have many2many field in a model. Problem i am facing is unable to get other record ids but only 1st id.

field_name = fields.Many2many('res.partner')

```
for rec in self:
for customer in rec.field_name:
table_name = self.env['custom.model'].search([('customer_id','=',customer.id)])
for x in table_name:
    x.write({'value': value})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will always return one record set because of your domain search `customer.id`.

Not sure your goal, but if you want to search similar customer name, use following domain.

```
self.env['custom.model'].search([('customer_id.name', 'ilike', customer.name)])
```

OR

Use search domain value without customer id.

Comment: is it possible to use mapped() function?
And how can i use mapped() function's result in loop to filter records?